# Group multiple columns using the CASE Condition function

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I am grouping a rows in mysql using two columns `userfrom` and `userto`.  I have to select only one message of conversation between a and b. The below query does exactly what I want, but I wanted to deploy this into android sqlite query, however the sqlite takes only the CASE Condition function.

```
 SELECT * FROM messeages WHERE userfrom='a' OR userto='a' 
 group by 
     IF(userfrom > userto, userfrom,userto),
     IF(userfrom > userto, userto,userfrom)
```

Can someone help on translating this using the CASE Condition function.

Comment: Using `SELECT * ... GROUP IF(userfrom > userto, userfrom,userto),
     IF(userfrom > userto, userto,userfrom)` doesn't make anny sense. MySQL premits to run this faulty query.. your query really needs a rewite.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case) documents how this works:

```
GROUP BY CASE WHEN userfrom > userto THEN userfrom ELSE userto END,
         CASE WHEN userfrom > userto THEN userto ELSE userfrom END;
```

However, in this case, you can simply use the non-aggregated form of [min()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#minoreunc)/[max()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#maxoreunc):

```
GROUP BY max(userfrom, userto),
         min(userfrom, userto);
```

Comment: i doubt this will work correctly in combination with `SELECT *`

Comment: It will result in one output row per user pair, so any columns except user-related ones do not make sense. But that is not the question.

Comment: i believe SQLite follows the ANSI SQL standard about the GROUP BY rules. So every column used in de SELECT should also been used in the GROUP BY.. Correct me if iam wrong.

Comment: SQLite allows any random thing in the SELECT; in some cases, this is [a feature](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bareagg).

Comment: Ok just like MySQL does when sql_mode only_full_group_by is not enabled . still meaning the column what is not named in GROUP BY will contain a "random" value.. Ok i learned something new today about SQLite.